# I want to use the response from httppost method in onpostexecute?

Tags: android

I am using httppost method in doinbackground and I am also getting the the response. Now when I pass the data to webservice I get a Jsonobject which I have to parse. and that jsonobject is stored in responsebody below. I have putted the return statement as "res". but in onpost execute I get a nullpointer exception.

I want to use the String responseBody in onpostexecute method?

```
class Thread extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String>{

    private String responseBody;
    private String res;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url1);

        try {
            json.put("URL",getqrcode());
            json.put("EmailID", getuseremail());
    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(json.toString());

            stringEntity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");
            post.setEntity(stringEntity);

            response = client.execute(post);
            Log.e("RESPONSE", response.toString());
            String responseBody = EntityUtils
                    .toString(response.getEntity());
            String res= responseBody.toString();

            Log.e("RESPONSE BODY", responseBody);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return res;
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
    Log.e("response is", res);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Global variable of response

```
String res;
```

and use in **onpostExecute(**) method:

and just replace

```
String res= responseBody.toString();
```

with

```
res= responseBody.toString();
```

only

Comment: and how this will help?

Comment: ok, but not Global ... just in doInBackground scope ... because now it is in try scope ... good finding :)

Comment: No need to declare a global variable if we can do it in simple way as I wrote in my commen

Answer (score 0):

Your global `res` is masking the local `res` defined in the try block.

Since the `res` variable you populate is local to the scope of the try block, it cannot be seen outside, and your compiler doesn't complain because of the global `res`.

You can simply affect the `res` member without re-declaring it:

```
res = responseBody;
```

Technically, it is not useful to declare the `res` variable globally, you can simply declare it in the method, but in the same scope as the return, that is, outside the try block (before it).

(also, the `toString` is not useful, as it will only return itself in the case of a `String`)

(the same goes for responseBody, the local scope hide the global scope. In this case, the global scope is useless)

Answer (score 0):

Just insert this statement in the end of your doInBackground method :

```
return res;
```

This will return response to `onPostExecute(String oString)` wrap-up in oString